# Rails is not inputting user data to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I am having an issue with Rails not inputting values to postgresql. The database itself is connected. When I run db:create:all (snippet from database.yml)

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: website_development
  username: postgres
  password: *******
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 9435
```

(test: is the same but with database: website_test instead of website_development) all the databases are created for test and development. When I run my db:migration the user table is also created e.g. snippet from migration file "date"_create_user.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up

    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

(I have checked in pgAdmin and found the tables that where created)But when I try to insert data from the console e.g.(this was run in sandbox)

```
irb(main):001:0> User.create!(:username => "John", :email => "john@example.com)
=> #<User id: 1, username: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2011-04-26 22:00:28", u
pdated_at: "2011-04-26 22:00:28">
```

here is the sql produced on a different create! I had run

```
[1m[35mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2011-04-26 20:53:43.363908', '2011-04-26 20:53:43.363908') RETURNING "id"
```

Any help as to why rails is creating the databases and tables fine but can't find the proper username and email to enter into sql.

P.S. I am running Rspec for my tests and have made several tests regarding the values of username and email not being nil to which all succeed.

```
......................
Finished in 1.62 seconds
22 examples, 0 failures
Notification failed: 201 - The destination server was not reachable
Notification failed: 201 - The destination server was not reachable
```

As you can see all Rspec tests are green but it to is having trouble connecting to the postgres server

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Update: added user model snippet

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :username, :email

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    username_regex = /\A[\w\d]+\z/i

    validates :username, :presence   => true,
                         :format     => { :with => username_regex },
                         :length     => { :maximum => 30},
                         :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
    validates :email,    :presence   => true,
                         :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                         :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

**==Answer==**

These were my mistakes:

Part 1: By changing `attr_accessor` to `attr_accessible` all my tests worked properly, and everything that needed to went to red, this also allowed me to add `:email` details but not `:username` details which leads to part 2.

Part 2: For some reason rails didn't like the fact that my table was named `:user` and my column was named `:username`. So I tried changing :username to `:loginname` which fixed the problem entirely.

Thank you everyone for all your help.

Comment: please post your user class. Looks like active record

Comment: also check pg_hba.conf to see if pg allows connections from the defined user from the outside via name/pw login

Answer (score 1):

To isolate this you may want to construct a unit test to replicate the problem, then repair it as required. At first I suspected it would be a case of protected attributes, but it appears you have made them accessible, which is the correct thing to do.

Calling `create!` directly is somewhat hazardous as you are not easily able to capture the object that is half-created in the event of an exception. This is because although the exception contains a reference to a model, it is not clear if the User model or some other model caused the exception in the first place without additional digging.

A more reliable approach is this:

```
def test_create_example
  user = User.new(:username => "John", :email => "john@example.com")

  assert_equal 'John', user.username
  assert_equal 'john@example.com', email

  user.save

  assert_equal [ ], user.errors.full_messages
  assert_equal false, user.new_record?
end
```

If an error occurs in the validation stream you will see the error listed alongside what should be an empty array. It also checks that the record has been saved by testing that it is no longer a new record as records can be valid but fail to save if a `before_save` or `before_create` filter returns `false`, something that happens by accident quite often.

If you call `new` and then `save` you have an opportunity to inspect the newly prepared object before it is saved, as well as after.

Comment: I have tried running a 'user = User.new' command. The result is that all the values are null and if 'user.save' is executed, which somehow evaluates to true, then I get the same result as if I were to have used 'create!'. Which is the id(incremented), username(nil), email(nil), created_at(created), updated_at(created)

Comment: You're having a problem assigning to your attributes, then, which indicates something is protecting them in the model. If that's the entirety of your User model, it should work fine, but perhaps you have an add-on like Devise that's messing with it externally.

Comment: Other than the annotation that is my entire User model. I am not running any authentication add-ons like Devise on this project. The only gems I am running are annotaion(for development), rspec and webrat(for tests).

Comment: I did try db:rollback but it didn't delete the tables from psql, so I manually deleted them and ran the migrate again. The migration worked and created the tables again, but I am still having the same problem. Also with the fact the `User.new` and `User.create!` are failing to create the username and email before hitting the database makes me think it is not a postgres issue.

Comment: You could try a test on the default sqlite engine to see if that side-steps it, or create a different model with the same internals but a different name and remove pieces until you can get it working. Looks like you need to narrow down the problem here if other models are operating as expected.